# modprobe not found at all

Tags: debian-squeeze, modprobe

I know that a lot of people had problems finding modprobe which was mostely due to an unconfigured $PATH. This time however I logged into a machine (Linux mymachine 2.6.32-6-pve #1 SMP Mon Jan 23 08:27:52 CET 2012 i686 GNU/Linux with root rights) and modprobe wasn't found at all. This are the steps I have taken so far:

```
- which modprobe => no results 
- locate modprobe => no results
- my $PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:
- find / -name "modprobe*" => /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe
- cat /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe => /sbin/modprobe
- /sbin/modprobe => no such file or directory
```

Ass you can see no modprobe at all. 
Does anyone else has a suggestion/ sollution so I can use modprobe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update for 2016, debian Jessie

(re)install `kmod` package

Answer (score 3):

Found it already myself. Just had to install module-init-tools again...
    aptitude install module-init-tools